# Partition external table by unixtime

Tags: azure-data-explorer, external-tables

Typically when partitioning an [external table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/schema-entities/externaltables), I will use 1-day boundaries with the syntax

```
.create external table extTbl (
    Timestamp: datetime,
    Data: dynamic
)
kind = blob
partition by (Timestamp:datetime = startofday(Timestamp))
...
```

However, I've come across a table with no `datetime` column. Instead, it contains `UnixTime: long` column for its timestamp.

First I tried `round()` to get to the start of the day.

```
.create external table extTbl (
    UnixTime: long,
    Data: dynamic
)
kind = blob
partition by (UnixTime:long = round(UnixTime/ 86400,0) * 86400)
...
```

...which returns `BadRequest_SyntaxError`. The same occurs when I try to cast to datetime...

```
.create external table extTbl (
    UnixTime: long,
    Data: dynamic
)
kind = blob
partition by (UnixTime:datetime = startofday(datetime_add('second',UnixTime,datetime(1970-01-01)))
...
```

The [examples given in docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/external-tables-azurestorage-azuredatalake#path-format) show use of some functions is permissible but I'm unsure which I have access to and which I don't.

How do I partition on this column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL;DR: it is not possible to partition on a numeric source column. You can create a new derived column in the export command though and partition on that.

Given...

```
.create table Tbl (
    UnixTime: long,
    Data: dynamic
)
```

...your external table will be...

```
.create external table extTbl (
    UnixTime_DT: datetime:
    UnixTime: long,
    Data: dynamic
)
kind = blob
partition by (UnixTime_DT:datetime = startofday(UnixTime_DT))
...
```

...and your export command will be of the form...

```
.export async to table extTbl <|
Foo
| where UnixTime >= tolong((datetime({Start})/timespan(1s))-62135596800)
| where UnixTime <  tolong((datetime({End})/timespan(1s))-62135596800)
| extend UnixTime_DT = unixtime_seconds_todatetime(UnixTime) 
| project-reorder UnixTime_DT
```

...leveraging the [`unixtime_seconds_todatetime()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/unixtime-seconds-todatetimefunction) (or [milli](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/unixtime-milliseconds-todatetimefunction)/[micro](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/unixtime-microseconds-todatetimefunction) variants) in the export query because it is not allowed in the DDL command.

n.b. the offset "62135596800" is the number of seconds between 1970-01-01 and 0001-01-01.

---

> *...use of some functions is permissible but I'm unsure which...*

The ["Partitions formatting"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/external-tables-azurestorage-azuredatalake#partitions-formatting) section of the docs appears to list a very limited shortlist of functions.

- [hash](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/hashfunction)
- [startofyear](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/startofyearfunction) | [startofmonth](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/startofmonthfunction) | [startofweek](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/startofweekfunction) | [startofday](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/startofdayfunction)
- [bin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/binfunction)

> *First I tried `round()`...*

The ["Virtual columns"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/external-tables-azurestorage-azuredatalake#virtual-columns) notes "*Virtual columns can be of either type `string` or `datetime`*"... which would seem to prevent use of [`round()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/roundfunction) (which returns a numeric type) were that reading not confounded by the fact that it is possible for both `bin()` and `hash()` to return numerics.

---

You can vote for expanded coverage of this use case at the [Azure feedback forum](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/19554e4a-bc41-ee11-a81c-0022484c92b1).